# Can I prevent Mist downloading the blockchain?

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, sshfs

I am using Mist Browser on a laptop at IP = .12 on the local network.
Elsewhere on IP = 25, I have an RPi running a node from http://parity.io/.  The command is

```
/usr/bin/parity --warp --cache 256  --public-node
```

I noticed that the Parity client has a

```
/usr/bin/parity --geth
```

option which I am not using, but as I understand it, this node supposedly implements the Ethereum protocol, so I should be able to tell my local Mist that the RPi has the blockchain.

In case it's any help, the ONLY open port is 22 (no RPC), and no JSON-RPC or config.toml anywhere.  Neither is there any chaindata directory.

```
$ find . -name chaindata -print
```

What I really want is to mount the ~/.ethereum/geth/chaindata from the RPi so that block data (such as) .ethereum/geth/chaindata/000186.ldb are available on the laptop as Mist starts, so that Mist won't download the whole blockchain again.

I'll probably need to use the Go client because the --geth mode seems to produce the same directory structure on the RPi.  The Parity.io node is written in Rust, and that might explain why I can't find the files I was looking for.

Has anyone tried this, or can anyone tell me if they've managed to start Mist so that it "borrows" the blockchain mounted from the local LAN?

Answer (score 0):

we actually tried on [IBM Blochain](https://www.ibm.com/blockchain/) platform  but we also failed to start Mist